# Can I restore previous class removed by removeClass className.match?

Tags: jquery, classname

i need to remove some classes from different tag by clicking on button "List View" , and restore classes removed before by clicking "Grid View" button; is it possibile to do that ?

Thanks

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

$("#addClass").click(function () {
          $('#restoreclass').addClass('previousclasses');
            });
          
            $("#removeClass").click(function () {
        
          $(".products").removeClass (function (index, className) {
            return (className.match (/(^|\s)columns-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        });
        
      $("#wc-column-container").removeClass (function (index, className) {
            return (className.match (/(^|\s)wc-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        });
      
            });
    
        });
```

```
   <input id="addClass" type="button" value="Grid View" />
   <input id="removeClass" type="button" value="List View" />
```

Comment: Please make [mre], with the rest of  HTML code and CSS not just buttons. I dont understand from this what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the class names in a data-attribute before removing them and restore them when clicking the "Grid View" button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#addClass").click(function() {
    $(".products, #wc-column-container").each(function() {
      let prev = $(this).attr("data-previous");
      prev = prev.replace(/\,/g, '').trim();
      $(this).addClass(prev).removeAttr("data-previous");
    });
  });

  $("#removeClass").click(function() {
    $(".products").removeClass(function(index, className) {
      let classNames = className.match(/(^|\s)columns-\S+/g);
      $(this).attr("data-previous", classNames);
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)columns-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    });

    $("#wc-column-container").removeClass(function(index, className) {
      let classNames = className.match(/(^|\s)wc-\S+/g);
      $(this).attr("data-previous", classNames);
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)wc-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="addClass" type="button" value="Grid View" />
<input id="removeClass" type="button" value="List View" />
<div class="products columns-a columns-b">
Products
</div>
<div id="wc-column-container" class="wc-a wc-b">
Example
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, i think may be an error in `prev = prev.replace(",", "").trim();` because when I restore it the classes appear separated with comma class="wc-columns-container, wc-columns-3, wc-tablet-columns-2, wc-mobile-columns-1", could you help ? Thanks

Comment: @AlessioAngeloro I've just adjusted my answer so all commas get replaced with an empty string.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very guru with JS, which comma I must remove ? Thnaks.

Comment: @AlessioAngeloro You don't have to remove a comma, I've adjusted in my answer the line prev = prev.replace(",","").trim(); with prev = prev.replace(/\,/g, '').trim(); so all commas are taken care of instead of just the first one.

Comment: Thanks now working.

Now I need to do this :

After first click on list view, disable button until the user click the grid view; I'm tring with this code but not working :

https://codeshare.io/G8WWD4

Comment: @AlessioAngeloro You can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/er1ywpsj/ Also if this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to this answer so your question is resolved as answered/solved.

Comment: You are my hero :-) Thanks you so much.

Alessio

Comment: @AlessioAngeloro Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: @AlessioAngeloro Just in case you don't know how accepting an answer works, have a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235